# Linq - Getting object with enum where clause

Tags: c#, linq

I am making a program where a team can "draft" players. Instead of the teams choosing the best player available I want a team to select the best player (by overall) which plays on a position a team has the least amount of players from.

The Player class:

```
public enum Position { PG,SG,SF,PF,C};

    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public Position Position { get; private set; }
    public int Id { get;}
    public int TeamId { get;}
    public int Overall { get; private set; }
    public int InsideScoring { get; private set; }
    public int MidScoring { get; private set; }
    public int ThreeScoring { get; private set; }
    public int Passing { get; private set; }
    public int BallHandling { get; private set; }
    public int PerimeterD { get; private set; }
    public int InsideD { get; private set; }
    public int Rebounding { get; private set; }
    public int Steals { get; private set; }
    public int Blocks { get; private set; }
    public int Strength { get; private set; }
```

The Team class

```
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Hometown { get; set; }
    public string Teamname { get; set; }
    public Color Teamcolor { get; set; }
    public List<Player> teamPlayers { get; set; } = new List<Player>();
```

In my Draft class, I have the following "relevant" code.

```
void getPlayers()
    {
        allPlayers = new List<Player>();
        allPlayers = sql.Select("Select * from player");
        var source = new BindingSource();
        source.DataSource = allPlayers;
        dgAllPlayers.DataSource = source;
        dgAllPlayers.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
    }
 Team nextTeam;
 List<Player> allPlayers;
 void nextUP()
        {
            if (nextTeam.UserControlled == 0)
            {
                Player ChosenPlayer = aiChoose(nextTeam);
                nextTeam.teamPlayers.Add(ChosenPlayer);
                allPlayers.Remove(ChosenPlayer);
                dgAllPlayers.DataSource = null;
                dgAllPlayers.DataSource = allPlayers;
            }
             nextUP();
        }

    private Player aiChoose(Team team)
    {
        //get best player available
        Player ChosenPlayer = allPlayers.MaxBy(x => x.Overall);
        return ChosenPlayer;
    }
```

So in the aiChoose method my Linq Query should be replaced. I am well aware that this is also possible by using forloops but I think it's better to do it with Linq right?

Comment: Is `allPlayers.OrderByDescending(p => p.Overall).FirstOrDefault()` what you mean by MaxBy?

Comment: Have you tried `allPlayers.OrderByDescending(x => x.Overall).FirstOrDefault();`?

Comment: @vc74 yes exactly I'm using moreLinq in my project

Comment: I am unclear what the question is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the best player playing as a random remaining position:

```
Random random = new Random();
Position[] allPositions = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Position)) as Position[];

private Player ChooseNextPlayer(Team team)
{
    var positionsToAllocate = allPositions.Except(team.TeamPlayers.Select(p => p.Position));
    var randomNotAllocatedPosition = positionsToAllocate.ElementAt(random.Next(positionsToAllocate.Count()));

    return allPlayers.Where(p => p.Position == randomNotAllocatedPosition).MaxBy(p => p.Overall);
}
```

Comment: Sorry totally forgot to add my Position enum in code, please see the edit

Comment: also what does the field "p" mean?

Comment: I updated my answer with Position and Where part fixed, does it make sense to you?

Comment: I don't think I my question was clear. There are 5 possible positions: PG,SG,SF,PF,C. Imagine a team already having players with the following positions: 1 PG, 1 PF, and 1 C. So the next player's position should either be a SG or a SF, randomly. And then it should select the player from allPlayers which is that position and has the highest overall